# How do I get firestore documents with a where() and count it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In what I've done, users will select according to what they want.

the `selected` variable here store the value of what the user has selected. I could already get the value of the `selected` here.

Below are my codes:

```
  const [size, setSize] = useState(0)

  const getData = async () => {
    const citiesRef = firestore.collection("users");
    const snapshot = await citiesRef
      .where("item.itemName", "==", selected)
      .get();
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      setSize(doc.data());
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  console.log(size.length)
```

Currently, if I'll `console.log(size)` or `console.log(doc.data())`, it won't display anything. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`size`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#size) property to check number of documents in the [`querySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot).

```js
const [size, setSize] = useState(0)

const getData = async () => {
  const citiesRef = firestore.collection("users");
  const snapshot = await citiesRef
    .where("item.itemName", "==", selected)
    .get();
  setSize(snapshot.size)
};
```